# Invalid type (NULL) for variable

Tags: r

So I have this data-

```
hours     A      B      id
    2.9      1      1      1
    2.3      1      1      2
    2.3      1      1      3
    2.5      1      1      4
    4.6      1      2      1

    attach(hayfever.data)
hayfever.lm = lm(hayfever.data$hours ~ hayfever.data$A * hayfever$B)
```

But I get this error -

```
Error: invalid type (NULL) for variable 'hayfever.data$A'
```

I get the same when I do this-

```
   hayfever.lm = lm(hayfever.data$hours ~ A * B)
```

except the variable name changes.

Why is that happening?

[image]

Output of dput

```
## structure(list(hours = c(2.9, 2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 4.6, 4.4, 4.9, 4.5, 
## 4.8, 4.5, 4.4, 4.6, 5.8, 5.2, 5.2, 5.3, 8.4, 9.1, 8.7, 9, 9.1, 
## 9.4, 8.7, 9.4, 6.4, 5.7, 5.9, 7.2, 9.9, 10.5, 10.6, 12.1, 13.5, 
## 13, 13.3, 16.2), A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
## 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
## 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), B = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
## 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
## 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
## ), id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
## 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
## 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("hours", "A", "B", "id"
## ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

Comment: What does `str(hayfever.data)` display? Have you tried `hayfever.lm = lm(hours ~ A * B, data=hayfever.data)`? Also, you shouldn't use `attach`...

Comment: don't use attach.. ever really.

Comment: when I run str(hayfever.data) I get this-

## 'data.frame':    36 obs. of  1 variable:
##  $ hours.....A......B......id: Factor w/ 36 levels "    2.3      1      1      2",..: 4 1 2 3 9 5 12 7 11 8 ...

Comment: also ialm, I tried that - hours is not found when I type that

Comment: Hey @praks5432, edit your question to include the output that you get when you type `dput(hayfever.data)`. Or, if that is too large, please give us the output when you type `dput(head(hayfever.data))`

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `attach` here. This How you should do :

```
lm(hours ~ A * B,data=hayfever.data)
Call:
lm(formula = hours ~ A * B, data = hayfever.data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            A            B          A:B  
        0.4           NA          2.1           NA
```

Where the data is:

```
hayfever.data <- read.table(text='hours     A      B      id
+     2.9      1      1      1
+     2.3      1      1      2
+     2.3      1      1      3
+     2.5      1      1      4
+     4.6      1      2      1',header=TRUE)
```

Comment: I get object 'hours' not found

Comment: No. I edit my answer to use the same data variable name. Should work with for you now.

Comment: yeah- same deal - I hours is not found

Comment: @praks5432 test it in a new R session. You get all this harm because of the `attach`

Comment: I'm using a KnitR document - so how do I do that?

Comment: I also tried this in the console in RStudio - same deal

Comment: This is basic usage of `lm` and data frames. The problem is on your end, and we cannot really diagnose what the problem is from over here.

Comment: ok...so I opened a new markdown document and pasted the above code - but I have the same issue

Comment: I'm taking this data from an url - will that matter?

Comment: @praks5432 **How** are you taking the data? Create a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) already!

Comment: through read.table - I'm taking it from an url - btw in RStudio I noticed in my environment that there are no real headings for my data - I'll post an image

Answer (score 1):

If I input the data into R using the output from your `dput`, your code works.

```
hayfever.data <- structure(list(hours = c(2.9, 2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 4.6, 4.4, 4.9, 4.5, 
4.8, 4.5, 4.4, 4.6, 5.8, 5.2, 5.2, 5.3, 8.4, 9.1, 8.7, 9, 9.1, 
9.4, 8.7, 9.4, 6.4, 5.7, 5.9, 7.2, 9.9, 10.5, 10.6, 12.1, 13.5, 
13, 13.3, 16.2), A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), B = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("hours", "A", "B", "id"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))

hayfever.lm <- lm(hours ~ A * B, data=hayfever.data)
hayfever.lm

# Call:
# lm(formula = hours ~ A * B, data = hayfever.data)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)            A            B          A:B  
#      1.9833       0.4208      -0.5542       1.4062
```

There is probably some lingering problem in your R session, maybe from `attach`? `attach` is evil. Don't ever use it. Seriously, it causes many headaches.

Try following some of the advice in the comments and clear your workspace, then restart your R session. Do not use `attach`.

Curiously, your attached screenshot does not match the data that I read in from your `dput` output.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with the swiss data set. Turns out my problem was because of case sensitivity. D'oh! Basically, R's telling us that the referenced variable does not exist, so we'd maybe better look to our naming/spelling for a solution. I'm using Microsoft's R distribution, so maybe others aren't so picky?

```
> lm(swiss$catholic~swiss$fertility, swiss)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = swiss$catholic ~ swiss$fertility,  : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'swiss$catholic'
> lm(swiss$Catholic~swiss$Fertility)

Call:
lm(formula = swiss$Catholic ~ swiss$Fertility, swiss)

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)  swiss$Fertility  
        -67.441            1.548  

>
```